# Can I execute multiple queries using sqli multi_query but only return one result

Tags: php, mysqli, mysqli-multi-query

I am executing multiple SQL insert commands and one select query in a single request to the database server but I get back a result for each command as well.

Simplified example:

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO table1 (column1) VALUES (123);' .
         'SET @id = LAST_INSERT_ID();' .
         'INSERT INTO table2 (column1, column2) VALUES (@id, 456);' .
         'INSERT INTO table3 (column1, column2) VALUES (@id, 789);' .
         'SELECT @id';

$conn = new mysqli('server', 'user', 'pass', 'name');

if ($conn->multi_query($query)) {
    do {
        if ($result = $conn->store_result()) {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
                printf("%s\n", $row[0]);
            }
            $result->free();
        }
    } while ($conn->next_result());
}
```

This results in three empty results and the fourth is the one I want.

Is it possible to not return results for the non-queries (the INSERTs and SET) and only get one result (for the SELECT) so I don't have to go through each to get what I want?

NB. Not wanting to use a stored procedure for this due to the complexity and variability of the dynamically generated INSERTs

Comment: just dont use multi_query, its a night mere to debug and really has no benefit over running each query individually

Comment: @smith, wouldn't there be some benefit making a single round trip to the DB if there was 5-10 inserts?

Comment: not really, feel free to benchmark it, you will find the difference minute

Comment: Of course you can use a stored procedure for one call!

Comment: @Parfait, some of the inserts are a bit beyond a stored procedure because there is a variable number of items that needed to be inserted depending on certain factors.

Comment: Your example here shows nothing that cannot be done in stored proc. You can still pass PHP values as parameters to a MySQL stored proc.

Comment: @Parfait, my example is only a simplification. The reason I am not using  a stored procedure is that the number of inserts varies and it I don't believe it is practical to move the logic that determines these inserts from php into a stored procedure.

Comment: Unless you are building dynamic queries, I still think stored procs are doable here. Here it shows already build SQL statements. In your stored proc, you can write ALL possible inserts with conditions by `if` logic from input parameters. Post actual use case for more help.